# Merge drive c: and d: whilst drive D: has program files

Tags: windows-xp, partitioning, merge, hard-drive

I have two partitions on my laptop and would like to merge drive D: to C: but, drive D: has program files in it and drive C: has the OS. I am running out of space on drive C: and would eventually like to merge the two drives. Please help. I'm running an XP professional.

Answer (score 4):

Merging the drives will always be a problem with anything but data on one of them. That said, if you have partitioning software that would merge partitions, you probably have software that will allow you to resize them, and I recommend that you only rsize them.

If you do not have such software, go here and try the free version:

http://www.partition-tool.com/download.htm

Comment: +1 QFT - merging the two drives is just asking for headache. Just steal space from one to give to the other.

Comment: +1 Many applications put path data in the registry in arbitrary locations. After the merge, you may find that most of your programs stop working or begin behaving strangely.